# Converting time from sheets to app script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Cell A1 = 8:00 pm.
Here's my code in App Script-

```
var sheetTime = sheet.getRange("A1");
var time = Utilities.formatDate(sheetTime, TIMEZONE, "hh:mm a");
console.log(time) >>> 05:36 PM

OR

var sheetTime = sheet.getRange("A1");
console.log(sheetTime) >>> Sat Dec 30 1899 19:36:36 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

My timezones are set in settings and in app script.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. `Utilities.formatDate()` accepts a date object ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)) while you are passing a range.  You need to add one extra step:

   ```js
   var sheetTime = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
   var time = Utilities.formatDate(sheetTime, TIMEZONE, "hh:mm a");
   ```
2. Google Sheets store date and time as numbers from Dec 30, 1899. It looks like at that time there were no time zones or they were different, so it adds 36:36 to the date object returned (the exact offset depends on your time zone). To compensate for that you will need to subtract that extra time:

   ```js
   var sheetTime = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
   sheetTime = new Date(sheetTime - (36 * 60 + 36) * 1000);
   var time = Utilities.formatDate(sheetTime, TIMEZONE, "hh:mm a");
   ```

Comment: My mistake. I do have .getValue(). Anything else you see wrong?

Comment: @Dave I have tested the updated code, so that's it.

Comment: Does it matter that a script is setting "A1" from api data?

Comment: @Dave What matters in this case, is that the data in the cell is properly recognized as a date by Google Sheets, which depends on the data itself and cell formatting.  The exact source of the value is not that important.

Comment: It's happening even when I create a new spreadsheet.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w2LAtd1Qd35ah-W1QWAVCaRdS1NXNIDEJivV0TXyri8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Dave Thank you for the working spreadsheet example.  Much easier to debug.  There is a second issue there with timezones and how sheets store time.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this;

I find that new Date() will convert a spreadsheet date object into a javascript date object.

```
const ss = SpreadSheetApp.getActive();
var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm a");
```